# Using UNION across databases | SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I wan't to get informations which are safed in 2 databases with only one mysql query, using the `UNION` statement.

The first to selects are for the database `sport` the other from `dewiki`.

If i send this request, there is no error, but there are up to 29 `BLOB`-results.

which if i open it are filled with errors like `SELECT page_title
FROM dewiki.page: Database '' does not exist.`

**This is my sql-statement:**

```
(SELECT teamName FROM sport.leagueTeams WHERE teamName LIKE '%werder%')
UNION
(SELECT leagueAlias FROM sport.leagueAlias WHERE leagueAlias LIKE '%bundesliga%')
UNION
(SELECT title FROM dewiki.cachedArticles WHERE title LIKE '%werder%')
UNION
(SELECT page_title FROM dewiki.page WHERE page_title LIKE '%werder%')
```

Comment: Before running Union query, first try running these statements individually from the same window. Does all of them run correctly?

Comment: Yes I tryed it and all of them run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all parenthesis!!!

They break the correct syntax as they transform each individual select into a subquery.  `Union` joins two or more querys, not subquerys

Comment: ok i tryed but nethertheless he returns the blob-results with a other error: `mysql return a empty result (t.h. zero datasets)`

Comment: that is not an "error", that means that any record mets the desired criteria

Comment: but why returns for example the first statement without the other a result but with the other statements it returns a empty result?

Comment: Try changing the order of your SELECT statements.

Comment: Order by which Column? can u make a example?